# Solving non-linear differential equation with respect to a parameter

Tags: plotting, differential-equations

I want to solve this equation and get a 2-dimensional plot with `N2` on `X-axis` and `theta(1)` on the `Y-axis` with `x from 0 to 1` and `N2 varies from 0 to 5`

```
theta''[x] + theta'[x] - 
   (N2)^2*theta[x] +theta[x]^3 == 0, theta'[1] == 1, 
 theta[0] == 0
```

I am new to Mathematica.

Comment: This is not solving your complete problem, but it is showing you how to solve a similar problem. First do this `sol=theta[x]/.DSolve[{theta''[x]+theta'[x]-(N2)^2*theta[x]==0, theta'[1]==1, theta[0]==0},theta[x],x]` and then do this `Plot[Table[sol,{x,0,1,1/8}],{N2,0,5}]` and see what you get. Then look up `DSolve` and `Plot` and `Table` and `/.` in the help system and study the examples. Try to understand what each part of this is doing. Then make tiny changes and see what happens until you think you understand this. Including the `theta[x]^3` term fails. Can you solve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The desired situation can be plotted like this but you need to make sure your equation and boundary conditions are correct.

```
sol = Table[{N2, theta[1] /. First@NDSolve[{theta''[x] + theta'[x] -(N2)^2*theta[x] 
+ theta[x]^3 == 0, theta'[1] == 1, theta[0] == 0}, theta, {x, 0, 1}]}, {N2, 0, 5, 0.5}];

ListLinePlot[sol, PlotRange -> All]
```

Answer (score 3):

If you look for a numerical solution try `ParametricNDSolveValue[]` which gives a parameter dependent solution

```
sys = {theta''[x] + theta'[x] - (N2)^2*theta[x] + theta[x]^3 == 0,theta'[1] == 1, theta[0] == 0}
\[Theta] = ParametricNDSolveValue[sys, theta, {x, 0, 1}, {N2}]
```

The solution can be accessed in  the form  `\[Theta][2.5][x]` (*first bracket=parameter, second bracket x*)

```
Plot[\[Theta][2.5][x], {x, 0, 1},AxesLabel -> {"x", "\[Theta]"}]
```

[image]

The plot you asked for gathers the different solutions inside `Table`

```
Plot[Table[\[Theta][n2][x], {n2, 0, 5, 1}] // Evaluate, {x, 0, 1}, AxesLabel -> {"x", "\[Theta]"}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

That's it!